# Why are there yellow dot stickers on the front doors of businesses in Russia?

Tags: russia

In both Moscow and Saint Petersburg, I’ve seen many/most businesses with a yellow dot sticker on the front door. Right in the center, around 10cm or less in diameter. What does it mean and why is it there?

[image]

Comment: These are called glass awareness stickers, they come in a lot of varieties (here is [a link to Amazon where you can buy them](https://www.amazon.com/Awareness-Stickers-CIRCLES-Effect-Frosted/dp/B077PPKP9N)). They are a safety measure to warn people of glass doors and other large clear glass panels. You also see them as strips or a series of dots.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, this is an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: I remember seeing these on every single glass door throughout all of grade school and knew exactly what it was for. Is this no longer common?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus With modern health and safety rules, you need unbreakable "glass" (not necessarily real glass at all). If the kids are dumb enough to try to run through closed doors, either they learn from their first mistake, or "survival of the fittest" takes its natural course :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This means "there's a glass door, please don't go through it without opening first".

If it contains black curl, then it also means "you can order delivery via [Yandex.Food](https://eda.yandex/)" (a service similar to Uber Eats and friends where you order via smartphone app or web browser).

[image: Logo]

Comment: I thought that might be it, but then I also saw them on wood doors with no glass at all. I also would imagine it would be on both doors, when glass, and not just one. But it’s usually still just one door with the dot.

Comment: In your picture there are other stickers on the other door so you wouldn't need one there.  Seeing them on wood (or mainly wooden doors with glass in as pictured) seems odd

Comment: https://thequestion.ru/questions/119215/chto-oznachayut-zheltye-krugi-na-vkhodnykh-dveryakh-kak-pravilo-na-dveryakh-bankov says I'm right - it's for people with poor eyesight. Not sure it's needed on wood doors. Probably people prefer to overdo.

Comment: Or someone copied something without knowing its meaning.

Comment: Does it show which of a pair of doors is to be pulled/pushed first?

Comment: @chris-h I didn’t mean this exact door. I’ve seen it in other cases where both doors are glass, one has the sticker, and the other does not (and there is nothing else on that door at all).

Comment: Yea it’s strange, I’ve seen it on doors with hardly any glass and/or covered with so many other stickers anyway. Seems strange to need to put an extra one in those cases, unless it’s mandatory. However, it seems to not be mandatory. It’s also much less common in St Petersburg than in Moscow.

Comment: It could also be a sticker that has something on the other side, like a warning for a step or it being an automatic door. https://rlv.zcache.com/caution_sign_automatic_door_classic_round_sticker-rfe3809de5b80403cbbf0d822b4f82b95_0ugmp_8byvr_540.jpg

Comment: It may be also the door to try. For some reason, in Russia you can only open one half of a door, this including paired glass doors. In this case, yellow circle helps, as you know which door to handle.

Comment: Why (inadvertently?) advertise a random food delivery service when it has no direct relation to the original question?

Comment: @Arnold because *some* yellow stickers may be not door-designating but delivery-promoting. Яндекс.Еда is so large anyway that promoting it is moot. That's like advertising Amazon.

Comment: @alamar Well, the door is really only the half that opens. The other "door" is locked in, and opened manually if you need to carry something wide through the door. It's a common design in residential buildings in Europe.

Comment: @alamar The UK also likes to keep one half of most double-doors locked shut. See, despite politicians trying to drive us apart, we're all just the same.

Comment: @solidcell *I also saw them on wood doors with no glass at all* you should probably edit that into your question, it seems like a significant detail with respect to "it's a glass visibility sticker" being the correct answer or not.